# Sending bitmaps over ethernet and then back again (c# and c)

Tags: c#, c, sockets, tcp, bitmap

I'm looking to send bitmap (or image) over ethernet in order to perform some image processing, then send them back.
The 'client' is running c# code, extracting frames from a video using emgucv. The 'server' will be running c/c++ on an arm cpu, although at the moment is x86 on my laptop using elementary os. So I need to avoid using things like opencv for the image processing itself, but that's another point.

I looked into sockets etc and can send some data to/from the server, just text typed into a console at the moment.

From initial research, it seems like I'll need to convert the bitmap into a byte array in order to then send it, which I've done (I think) using the following code:

```
Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
    int l;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bmpFrame.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        byte[] byteFrame = ms.ToArray();
        l = byteFrame.Length;

        stm.Write(byteFrame, 0, byteFrame.Length);
        stm.Flush();
    }
```

Then on the server side trying to read it using:

```
char buff[10000];
int n;
n = read(conn_desc, buff, sizeof(buff)-1);
    if ( n > 0)
    {
    //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(receivedBytes);
    //Bitmap bmpReceived = new Bitmap(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        printf("Received %s\n", buff);
    }

   else
    {
        printf("Failed receiving\n");
    }
```

You can see the commented code where I thought I'd be able to change it back into a bitmap, but I'm not sure if I want/need to anymore, if I can just edit the images by accessing the bytes directly, and also I don't know how/if bitmaps work in C rather than C#.

Am I going along the right lines? Ideally I want to send all the data for a single frame, then do stuff to it, then send it back, but I've no idea if that's what I'm doing. Finding it more difficult than usual as on the server I'm just writing in scratch/gedit and using gcc to compile, having never coded on linux before so I'm missing things like intellisense/debugging.

Any help/recommendations would be appreciated

Comment: printf(%s...) only works with null-terminated strings.  A partially-received bitmap buffer is not a null-terminated string.

Comment: Bitmaps work the same in .NET as in unmanaged C++, in the sense that the formats are actually normal file formats (i.e. when you save to the `MemoryStream`, that's the same exact data you'd get if you'd saved to a file). So you need to find an example of how to interpret the data as a Windows .bmp format on your server side. You probably should be using .png anyway, both because it's compressed (but still lossless) and because you might have better support on Linux for .png than for .bmp (but really, .bmp is pretty broadly support as well).

Comment: The printf is kind of there from when I first setup the communication between the client and server and was just sending a string. I don't want to print it, I'll want to perform some image processing before sending it back.
Fair enough about PNG, is it easier to edit pixel values etc with PNG than BMP? For the interpolation, edge detection etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in short, I would say your approach for doing what you say you want to do is correct.

I would ask though, why are you sending it to the server? I'm guessing it has to do with parallel processing or something? Unless you're doing very heavy processing, working with a single frame is probably faster than transferring it to the server (as far as I know, EmguCV in C# isn't considerably slower than OpenCV in C/C++).

The System.Drawing.Bitmap class is part of the .Net framework, and you might not find a direct correspondance in C. You might want to consider first converting the image to some known format, such as a .png file. Then you send the raw bytes of that file. On the server side, you receive the raw byte array, and use whatever C struct to load that image as a .png file. The point is to remove some abstraction and have more precise knowledge of exactly what is being sent.

Perhaps it'd be easier to use something like the System.Net.WebRequest class? Again, it depends a bit on exactly what problem you're trying to solve.

I hope this helps at all - this response is a bit vague (your question is, too :P), so feel free to ask for clarification on specific parts :)

Comment: The OP is using `ImageFormat.Bmp`, which is a normal .bmp file. It's not a .NET-specific format. .png would be better, because it's compressed, but either are equally valid for use by the receiving code.

Comment: It's being sent to a development board with an FPGA on to try and utilise, but first it will just run on the arm chip on the board. Since I'm wanting to perform some image processing (interpolation, edge detection, possibly some motion stuff) in order to try to implement some form of super resolution I think I want to avoid compressing the images.
Edit: Having just seen that PNG are lossless as well as compressed I may look into them, are they easier to deal with, changing pixel values etc?

Comment: No, they just take less space. What you would do is to compress as PNG, then send it, and decompress it on the other side before processing

Comment: Fair enough, does the commented code with the memorystream look correct? Aiming to then just invert the image or something similar before sending it back. To send it back would I just use the same code I used to send it in the first place?

Comment: The MemoryStream code looks right, but I won't say that it's gonna work for sure before I tested it. Did you try running it to see if it works? You could use the same method to send it back.

Comment: I tried adding a loop afterwards on the server like so:
    `m = write(conn_desc, buff, sizeof(buff)-1);
    if (m <0)
    {
        printf("ERROR writing to socket");
    }`

I think it works for one cycle but I'm not really sure, as if I put a printf in the success bit of the if, it does it multiple times whereas I thought it would only do it once per transfer (same with the original sending to the server)

Edit: Not sure how to format code in comments :(

Comment: I think this kind of discussion in the comments is out of line with Stackoverflow's intended purpose. At this point, you should have the answers you need to test it and try to solve the problem on your own. If you encounter a new problem, I think you should post a new question. Good luck :)